# Build openssl from source wtih link option “Integrity Check” in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, openssl

I want to add "IntegrityCheck" as a command line parameter to the linker when i build openssl 1.1.0 from source. How can i do it?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the "INSTALL" text file that comes with the source you can find this option:

> VAR=value
>
> ```
>                Assignment of environment variable for Configure.  These
>                work just like normal environment variable assignments,
>                but are supported on all platforms and are confined to
>                the configuration scripts only.  These assignments override
>                the corresponding value in the inherited environment, if
>                there is one.
>
>                The following variables are used as "make variables" and
>                can be used as an alternative to giving preprocessor,
>                compiler and linker options directly as configuration.
>                The following variables are supported:
>
>                LDFLAGS         Flags for the shared library, DSO and
>                                program linker.
> ```

So for windows you would need to run the configure script something like:

> perl Configure VC-WIN32 LDFLAGS="/INTEGRITYCHECK"

(I'm not sure on the exact syntax of the switch to pass through, so may need to drop the '/')

then run the normal nmake to build it.